# Pre Calculus Quadratic Function Help General Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from a live lecture, I took my own notes on the subject however my handwriting is too poor to be visible correctly, so I'll instead present the online version:
[Image of Quadratic Function General Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI5vs.png)

Everything that I have studied makes sense to me here. Using the formula to get the answer, all of which I understand and have followed on my own. However there's just one part I'm confused at and wish to understand;

How did 123 come out of 25 and 48? This may be a rule with fractions or formulas I was meant to learn in previous courses, however I simply do not really know how this answer is possible.

Would anyone be obliged to explain this small issue to me? Thank you.

Comment: There is an arithmetic mistake in the final line.  It should read $\frac{25}{8} + 6 = \frac{25}{8} + \frac{48}{8} = \frac{73}{8}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Consider retyping the original here in MathJax so that we don't need to interpret *anyone's* handwriting.